# Add hour and seconds to CartoDB/Torque animation

Tags: javascript, geoprocessing, web-mapping, carto, animation

A while ago I made a CartoDB/Torque animation that displayed hours and minutes while playing. Sujay v. helped me out with the code here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cartodb/xpxF4fSV7ZI

Essentially I changed some lines in the torque.js file as below:

```
torque.clock.set('<span id="month">' + date_arry[0] + ' ' + date_arry[1] + ', </span> <span id="year">' + date_arry[2] + ' ' + date_arry[3] + '</span>');
```

However I've come back to needing to do something similar, and the torque.js file has changed alot and I can't figure out how to implement something similar now. Would someone be able to advise? The source code is here:

https://github.com/CartoDB/torque/blob/master/dist/torque.uncompressed.js

Apologies I can't do this myself. I'm pretty good at SQL and GIS, but lacking the .js skills. :-(

Thanks

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy, torque provides bindings to get the animation time:

```
        // each time time changes, change:time is raised
        // changes.time contains the Date objects
        torqueLayer.on('change:time', function(changes) {
          var month_year = changes.time.toString().substr(4).split(' ');
          $('.mytimedisplay').text(month_year[0] + " - " + month_year[2]);
        });
```

The code is from here: https://github.com/CartoDB/torque/blob/master/index.html#L266